# What will be the pattern for UTF-8 in Json Schema?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I am trying to match a JSON file value which can only contains UTF-8 else it will show error.
I wrote script in python to validate the JSON file using JSON schema.
I used the following pattern in json schema but didn't catch all the cases:

```
"name":{
    "type":"string",
    "pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&*_~:?()\\[\\]\\-` '.+,/\"{} \\u0080-\u9fff]*$"
    }
```

For example:

If name: '힙합성애자' it shows error but it should pass the validation.
then when name: John"☮" Robert, it pass the validation but it should be failed.

What should my regular expression be to pass validation with such UTF-8 values?

Comment: A pattern to match “UTF-8” would be `.*`. Yes, that means *anything*. Usually you’re validating the result of parsed JSON, at which point character encoding is irrelevant. If it wasn’t valid UTF-8 it would fail the parse stage.

Comment: "힙합성애자" and "☮" are both Unicode. The UTF-8 representations in hex are "ed 9e 99 ed 95 a9 ec 84 b1 ec 95 a0 ec 9e 90 0a" and "e2 98 ae 0a", respectively. Are you looking for a particular character plane, like printable characters? Or filtering out symbols/emoji?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of validating that a string in JSON "only contains UTF-8" is meaningless. JSON strings are Unicode strings; the idea of a string *within* a JSON document having an encoding is mistaken. You already decoded it as part of decoding JSON; now it's just Unicode, agnostic of any encoding. JSON itself is always supposed to be encoded as UTF-8. So as near as I can tell, the pattern you want is `.*`.

Comment: Is there any way to catch the case like this? name: John"☮" Robert ,here name contains emoji

Comment: as it is not encoded properly so it need to be showed as error "☮"

Comment: @SaNa3819 I really don't know what you mean by that. What isn't encoded properly about it? I can see a ☮, so it must be encoded properly.

Comment: Are you saying I cannot name my baby girl ☮? https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/